# WebSocketSharp For Unity

Tags: unity-networking, websocket, socket

I have integrated WebSocketSharp with Unity 2018.4.14f1 and it works well with Android and IOS. I wanted to know that most of the other socket.io plugins for unity have a wrapper of Class Packet over the top which binds and sends packetID, EventType along with Data.

My question is, do we need to write such a wrapper for WebSocketSharp also in Unity?

Comment: Have you tried using it without such a wrapper? Did you encounter a specific snag or problem along the way that we can help you solve?

Comment: the data that i was trying to send was not getting sent to the server..i had to bind my data like this { "42":["test",{"name":"jack", "age":32}] }
where 42 is packet id.
test is the event callback.
and rest is data.

Comment: Cool. Did that solve your problem, or is there still a step you need help with?

Comment: yes sending like that above solved the problem

Comment: so i wanted to know do i need to make a wrapper class Packet to bind data like that for WebSocketSharp

Comment: If you would find that helpful, do it. If you're happy formatting your data without a wrapper, do it. What would a stranger have to add to this decision?

Comment: our server engineers are also using socket.io at the server side, so they expect the data in the above format..but if i use Websocketsharp..then there are two possiblities..one dont use socket.io on server side. second..wrap websocketsharp with a wrapper. so the question.